# Unable to resolve sun dependency after embedding JGIT dependency in AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

AEM: 6.5.12

JGIT:6.1.0

JavaEWAH:1.1.2

I am trying to embed JGit dependency to my pom.xml.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
   <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

by adding

```
<Embed-Dependency>someAnotherDependency,org.eclipse.jgit;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
```

This resulted another dependency not resolving which is

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.javaewah</groupId>
   <artifactId>JavaEWAH</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

which is something JGIT required. So added it to embed dependency as well

```
<Embed-Dependency>someOtherDependency,org.eclipse.jgit,JavaEWAH;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
```

When I added these two I got another dependency issue

[image: Vinit_Pillai_0-1652427977570.png]

the error on this one is not familiar to me.
When I remove my embedded dependencies (leaving one which was already there) the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not really need those dependencies, exclude them from your pom.xml using the `<Import-Packages>` section:

```
<Import-Package>
!sun.net.www.protocol.http,
!sun.security.jgss,
*
</Import-Package>
```